# How to turn off UPnP?

Tags: 13.10, upnp

Hi I am trying to figure out how to remove/turnoff this service: [UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play), I don't like having it on because I feel it may pose a security risk on my machine. I cannot find any guides or recipes on how to remove it completely / stop traffic from port 1900 and IP address 239.255.255.250 from sending data. I don't have any devices that rely on this service in my local home network and was looking for some help to get rid of it either in the kernel or removing the application. I am not 100% sure on what UPnP is really, even though it may not be a security risk I still don't like it running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use iptables to change firewall.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

something along the lines of
iptables -A --dport1900 -j REJECT

similar to this:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/turn-off-http-port-80-keep-https-port-443-a-288442/